# What kind of tree or bush was the "burning bush" of Moses?

Tags: history, moshe-rabbeinu, parashas-shemos, trees

I am looking for the kind of tree/bush for the burning bush of Moses. What are the kinds mentioned by Rabbis? I read before that some Rabbis identified the tree with the Sidr Tree. I need to know where specifically Sidr Tree (or cedar) is mentioned too.

Comment: I've edited your question to add some tags to help categorize it, and to remove the last bit which wasn't part of the question, to change the spelling of a word, and to make the title more clear. Feel free to look it over, and re-[edit] (or [rollback](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/94172/revisions)) if there is something you would like to change

Comment: What is the Seder plant?

Comment: @Alex I would guess cedar. See edit history.

Comment: The description of Sidr tree is in this link https://www.yemensidrhoney.com/sidr-tree

And according to Wikipedia Zizyphus spina is also called Sidr as רבות מחשבות showed 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziziphus_spina-christi, Also thank you for the good edit.

Comment: Is your question different from what it was [two years ago](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75724/what-kind-of-tree-was-the-burning-bush)?

Comment: @Alex, I think not

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most commentaries render this as some sort of thorny bush (see Rashi, Ibn Ezra).

In terms of identifying which exact species it may have been, a great resource is Rabbi Kaplan's Living Torah commentary to [Exodus 3:2](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=2&CHAPTER=3#C1023), which states:

> S'neh in Hebrew. This is most probably the black raspberry ([rubus sanctus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubus_ulmifolius_subsp._sanctus)), which has berries that turn red and then black (Yerushalmi, Ma'asroth 1:2, 3a; cf. Septuagint; Vulgate). The Midrash also identifies it as a species of thorn-bush (Sh'moth Rabbah 1:9, 2:9). Others identify it as the sana plant ([Casia obovata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senna_italica)), the shurbu ([Colutea istria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colutea)) [or] the wild juju ([Zizyphus spina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziziphus_spina-christi)).

Comment: Thanks for reply but if you know where Rabbis said it could be the Seder Plant it would be a valuable help, thanks

Comment: @GamalThomas I really can't find a source for that.  Sorry!

Comment: I have changed the word Seder to Sidr (misspelling from me), According to wikipedia (from your link) Zizyphus spina was called Sidr ... and was common in the Jordan. That is exactly what I was searching for. Many thanks to you. And if you give me the source for (Zizyphus spina) it would be so helpful, thank you.